Removing the "Copy" Button and Using Gestures to Copy Text in Chatbots
I'm interested in exploring the potential benefits of removing the "Copy" button and instead using a long press gesture to copy text in chatbots. I believe this approach could simplify the interface and make it more intuitive for users. However, I'm also aware that there could be some usability drawbacks, such as the potential for users to accidentally trigger the gesture or the lack of clear feedback indicating that the text has been copied. WHAT DO YOU GUYS THINK?

Your first concern is discoverability. Add a short reminder/notification of the gesture which can be dismissed by the user. The second concern is solved by adding an indication that the text has been copied. And you should test it with actual or potential users to know how often accidental triggering of the gesture  occurs and if it is even a real problem when it happens.

Are you talking about copying test to the clipboard? In a longer chat, all text or only the last reply? And what are the drawbacks of the Copy button you want to solve? After all, it's a short self-explanatory text, and every explanation/indication that long-press now does copy will take more space than "Copy".

Why do you think that would be more intuitive to users? Who are your users? I think every single user out there could intuit a copy button, whereas there's probably a significant portion of users that won't intuit they can long-press comments to copy.
Usability Heuristic #4 Consistency and Standards: Users should not have to wonder whether different words, situations or actions mean the same thing.
That said, I'm old and need to ask my teen about Insta and SnapChat sometimes so who your users are is probably the most important factor in considering whether this would be a benefit or drawback.
